# U.S. major cities busiest intersections?

Tags: usa, transportation, traffic

Is there a database of the busiest intersections in major U.S. cities?

Could this be figured out with, e.g., Google Maps API?

Comment: "Busiest" can mean a lot of different things from a data point of view, so it's hard to know which data to recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://trafficview.org/ presents Google Maps's traffic congestion data.